# Size of JPanel in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am trying to add a JPanel into my JFrame with a specific size. But whatever size I add to the JPanel, it always fills the whole entire JFrame. And I also tried to reposition the JButton according to my set position but it also doesn't work. Any recommendations or explanations anyone? Tq :P

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.; 
import java.awt.image.;

public class Login {

//Creating a method just for the login page0
static void Login(){
    JFrame LoginFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel Panel = new JPanel();

    Panel.setBounds(40,80,100,50);
    Panel.setBackground(Color.black);

    JButton Enter = new JButton();
    Enter.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    Enter.setBounds(50,100,80,30);
    Enter.setText("Enter");

    JButton Enter2 = new JButton();
    Enter.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    Enter.setBounds(50,100,80,30);
    Enter.setText("Enter");

    LoginFrame.setSize(420,720);
    LoginFrame.setBackground(Color.white);
    LoginFrame.setTitle("LoginFrame");
    LoginFrame.setVisible(true);
    LoginFrame.setLayout(null);
 }

public static void main(String[]args) {
    Login();
}
}
```

Comment: If I remember things correctly, you have to set the CONTENT PANE of the JFrame to use no (null) layout manager. The content pane has border layout (?) by default, therefore it allows for resizing and shrinks the content you add to it.

Comment: In addition to camickr's answer: 1) you didn't add the buttons to the frame 2) any operation to add content to a frame bust be done on it's content pane, not on the frame directly, see [How to use root panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) 3) Enter2 is an empty button since you didn't set anything on it, you set attributes on the other Enter button 4) Layout and all other things should be done before showing the frame

Comment: @Rocco *any operation to add content to a frame bust be done on it's content pane, not on the frame directly,* - Since about JDK3 or 4 you can add components to the frame and the frame will add the component to the content pane.

Comment: 1) `//Creating a method just for the login page0 static void Login(){` should be `//Creating a constructor just for the login page0 public Login(){` 2) A `Login` would typically use a `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane`. 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 3) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 4) There are multiple compilation errors in the code seen above. Post actual code in future.

Comment: 5) Why does the GUI have 2 buttons titled `Enter`? Is it meant to confuse and irritate the end user? 6) Those two buttons are given the same bounds..

Comment: @AndrewThompson it was just for show to test how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. These are Java conventions you will find in any text book or tutorial. Follow the examples.

> I am trying to add a JPanel into my JFrame with a specific size

Why use a random size? Swing is designed so that each component will determine its own size so it will work on any platform with any Look and Feel.

> Any recommendations

Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Layout managers make coding easier and more maintainable. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Also, you actually need to "add" the buttons to the panel and "add" the panel to the frame. The above tutorial demos show how to do that.

If you are simply trying to change the size of the buttons then use:

```
button.setMargin( new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20) );
```

The button will be sized properly based on the text AND the extra space specified.

If you want your panel to have extra space then you can use:

```
panel.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20) );
```

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information and examples.

> or explanations

The `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` by default. So the layout manager is resetting the size/location based on the rules of the layout manager. If you want a different layout, then use a different layout manager.